# How to use AzureAD for authentication in Vue / Hapi JS App

Tags: azure, authentication, jwt, azure-active-directory, msal.js

We have an app registered on the Azure Portal and we would like to use `MSAL.js` on the front-end and `hapi-auth-jwt2` with `jwks-rsa` on the back-end to authenticate users. The back-end is NOT hosted on Azure but our own MySQL server.

According to this example [active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp) we can use `MSAL.js` to login and either silently or with a pop up acquire ID and Access Tokens. We then attach the **access token** to the http header like this `Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token` and send a request with `axios` to our back-end `/login` route. When we hit the route from our client, `jwt` auth strategy kicks in and tries to decode the token using the keys retrieved with `jwks-rsa` from the public https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys.

The problem is that the response from `/login` comes with a `401 (Unauthorized)` and `res.headers.www-authenticate: "Bearer error=\"Invalid token\""`.

When we copy/paste the access token into jwt.io we noticed that our decoded header object consists of `typ`, `nonce`, `alg`, `x5t`, `kid` and the signature comes back as invalid. Also, our App registration had Microsoft Graph with `User.Read` selected under required permissions currently but we removed that.

To test whether the problem is in our JWT strategy, we passed the ID token to Bearer instead of the access token. JWT decoded the token but the response came back with `res.headers.www-authenticate: "Bearer error=\"Invalid credentials\""`

The questions we have are:

1. Is it possible to validate an access token without making a call to Graph API and how do we do that?
2. If the above is not possible can we authenticate a user using the ID token and how would that work?
3. If we can validate access token without a call to Graph API what should be the settings in https://portal.azure.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to define a scope for our API inside https://portal.azure.com and then create API permission with the newly created scope. The access token was successfully decoded by `hapi-auth-jwt2` after which we did another internal level of authentication inside the `validate()` function to return `isValid: true` if the internal auth returned correct results. Hope this helps somebody